# Exception construction service in hibernate when mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, tapestry

I am getting this exception when i run the application with two entities mapped

```
Exception constructing service 'ValueEncoderSource': Error invoking service contribution    method
 org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateModule.contributeValueEncoderSource(MappedConfiguration, boolean, HibernateSessionSource, Session, TypeCoercer, PropertyAccess, LoggerSource):
Exception constructing service 'HibernateSessionSource': Error invoking constructor public org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.HibernateSessionSourceImpl
```

I saw few suggestions that it might be hibernate/tapestry versions not supporting each other,
but what confuses me is the fact that it works just fine when I remove the mapping between entities. Just in case, i am getting release version of both tapestry and hibernate from these dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does anyone have an suggestion to what might be causing this, and way to solve it ?
If you need any further info just tell me, i will respond very quickly, since I need this app done asap.

Edit: Here is the full [trace](http://pastebin.com/vbjFq3YZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not attached the full stacktrace so all I can do is make a guess. If you are using Hibernate 4+ with Tapestry, it won't work as tapestry still uses Hibernate 3.6+. You can either use Hibernate 3.6+ or you can build tapestry-hibernate and tapestry-hibernate-core from sources with changes to the build.gradle/pom.xml file only.

Comment: I added the stacktrace. My hibernate version appears to be 3.6.0, Tapestry version is 5.3.6. Which changes you suggest i should make ? Just the versions in pom.xml ?

Comment: Never mind. I am just a blind exhausted dude trying to code, so it all came down to a typo... Had a wrong mappedBy atribute all along. Just noticed it now as i was again going through the stacktrace.